# Separate Windows' file copy from text copy

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I want to change Windows' copy function, i.e. if I copied text and copied a file they will both be saved in a buffer – and when I press paste in a text editor my text will be pasted. When I press paste button in any folder, my file will be pasted.

Is there any way I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: same issue has already logged, please check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113/is-there-any-way-to-override-the-drag-drop-or-copy-paste-behavior-of-an-existing

Comment: One thing you could do, is if a program intercepts the windows clipboard when text is involved, thus doesn't put it in the windows clipboard and puts it in its own clipboard only. Then when you copy/paste a file, it puts it in the windows "clipboard". Then that'd be close to what you want. As one hotkey would paste text the other would paste a file.

Comment: What you want is exactly what Windows clipboard is giving you already. So I do not understand what exactly you want to Change!?

Comment: @WernerHenze try copying some text then copy a file, then try pasting your text in any text editor, you will find that the text you copied is gone as windows is now holding file in its copy buffer.
I basically want windows to save these in different buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a good idea for a future windows version. You could call MS Customer services and see if they listen! In the meantime, try asking in the Autohotkey forum

And also in the meantime,

One thing you could do, is if a program intercepts the windows clipboard when text is involved, -and- doesn't put it in the windows clipboard and puts it in its own clipboard only. Then when you copy/paste a file, it puts it in the windows "clipboard". Then that'd be close to what you want. As one hotkey would paste text the other would paste a file.

Another possible way is if an alternative to windows clipboard is "powerful" enough, then it would allow copy/pasting of files. In which case, it might be able to do that or close to it e.g. do it but not quite as simply as control-v but pretty efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

This should be relatively easy to accomplish with an AutoHotkey script (a fantastic, mature, open source automation language).

The snippet below is part of a much larger script which is activated whenever I log in.  Any time I hit the CTRL+SHIFT+e key combo, it saves current Windows Clipboard content to a variable before opening a selected file in Notepad++ and then it writes the previous clipboard (the "clipback" variable) value back to the Windows Clipboard. It needs to copy the path of the selected file in order to open it, so without this feature, any clipboard content would be clobbered every time I use this shortcut to open a file in Notepad++.

With this script, I can click any type of file in any window (the Desktop, an Explorer window, a "File Open" dialog, etc.) and then hit the key combo to open it as text in Notepad++.  It's very useful for files whose association would normally cause them to be opened in another application.

---

;Edit in Notepad++
^+e::
 clipback = %clipboard%
 clipboard =
 SendInput {F2}{Esc}^c
 clipwait
 Sort clipboard
 run, C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%clipboard%"
 run, C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%clipboard%"
 run, C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "%clipboard%"
 clipboard = %clipback%
return

---

With a few modifications, it could override CTRL+C and CTRL+V, saving any text content before performing the a file copy or cut operation, and then restoring the text after the file is moved or copied.  If, for some reason, you don't want to leave AutoHotKey on your computer, an AutoHotKey script can be compiled and added to the Startup folder so that it will always be active when you need it.

I have been modifying Windows with AHK scripts for years.  It can do some pretty amazing things.